# Extract response x-authorization-token

Tags: jmeter

i'm trying to extract from response headers an x-authorization-token to a variable and pass to another http request, i'm new using jmeter.

Following online tutos, i have created an regular expression extractor do define a regular expression `x-authorization-token:\s+(.+)`

i want to pass `x-authorization-token: foo/bar` to another request

[Regular Expression Extractor conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inCwU.png)

Response headers example:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server-Timing: intid;desc=foo/bar
x-transaction-id: 34297420-432942-foo-bar
x-authorization-token: foo/bar
Date: Wed, 23 Jun 2021 22:54:24 GMT
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 2130
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 20
Via: kong/1.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the "another http request" and configure it as follows:

[image]

HTTP Header Manager allows defining arbitrary [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) so you can pass your `x-authorization-token` (as well as other headers if needed) to any request in the HTTP Header Manager's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Using JMeter's HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)